# Populate dynamic names and values into POJO in Struts2

Tags: java, struts2

I have a form with option to add multiple inputs vs value like below

```
name1 -> some data
name2 -> some data
name3 -> some data
name4 -> some data
...
```

upto `n` dynamic names

How to populate the POJO with dynamic names vs value in Struts2 and also how to retrieve those values in jsp using struts 2 jstl ?

Comment: By using map for example.

Comment: Why JSTL, and what did you try?

Comment: @RomanC after saving the form I have to show the details in jsp.

Comment: @AleksandrM how to put the form data into map ?

Comment: Isn't your previous question about that? http://stackoverflow.com/q/17698456/1700321.

Comment: @AleksandrM If I use map means I need to give the name like myform.map.key, it possible to avoid such name ?

Comment: What do you mean? Why do you care of inputs names?

Comment: @AleksandrM I just asking it is possible or not ? I don't want to give unwanted information into the name attribute.

Comment: Unwanted information? What? Maybe you need to show some code, to better illustrate what you are talking about.