# creating HashMap keys setter and getter dynamically

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts2, hashmap, jquery-jtable

I want to create variables like

```
  String user1;
  String user2;
  String user3;
```

etc...

and I have read somewhere that I should use HashMap.but how can I create setters and getters for each key of HashMap  so that I can add values from these user1,user2..(dynamically generated) text fields.I am using jQuery Jtableable.

**[EDITED]**

creating dynamic html fields using Ajax.(varies from 1 to 7)

```
                           session1 : {
                                            title : 'session1',
                                            width : '10%',
                                            edit : true
                                        },
                                        session2 : {
                                            title : 'session2',
                                            width : '10%',
                                            edit : true
                                        },
                                        session3 : {
                                            title : 'session3',
                                            width : '8%',
                                            edit : true
                                        },
                                        session4 : {
                                            title : 'session4',
                                            width : '8%',
                                            edit : true
                                        },
                                        session5 : {
                                            title : 'session5',
                                            width : '8%',
                                            edit : true
                                        },
                                        session6 : {
                                            title : 'session6',
                                            width : '8%',
                                            edit : true
                                        },
                                        session7 : {
                                            title : 'session7',
                                            width : '8%',
                                            edit : true
                                        }
```

my bean class

```
        class SessionElements
       {
            private String userName,regId,totalNumber;
            private int session1,session2,
               session3,session4,session5,session6,session7;
            //setters and getters
        }
```

ActionClass

```
        class CrudData
        {
            private String userName,regId,totalNumber;
            private int session1,session2,
               session3,session4,session5,session6,session7;
               //setters and getters
           public String execute()
           {
              //setting bean properties and inserting it using Hibernate
              return "success"
            }
         }
```

Comment: You wouldn't; you'd use hash access notation, e.g., `someHash['user1']` etc.

Comment: but struts needs setters and getters lets say i have html textfield username ,so there should be getUsername() and setUsername().how will struts link these fields with HashMap?

Comment: How would you do that in java code?

Comment: @stephanie The *hashmap* is the action property that's exposed.

Comment: If still isn't clear, you need getter/setter for the hashmap instance only. Then you can add elements with the above notation

Comment: sir I am new to struts, if you can please give me example snippet or link.and post it in answers section.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17698456/1700321.

Comment: please check the code edits and reply me back

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Could you elaborate more on what are you trying to do.

Comment: I have created dynamic HTML textfields with name attribute as session1,session2..... now how can I link these fields to my pojo class .in my code above(SessionElements.java) I have used private int session1,session2,...,session7 I don't want that instead of that I want to use HashMap.

Comment: @stephanie: Read again all answers from the post I've linked.